# Cannot resize NTFS Partition

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, ntfs

A family member recently asked me if I can "make their laptop run fast again".
When analyzing potential problems it was pretty clear that the storage is the biggest concern.
Almost 0% free space on all partitions and a very old and slow HDD (600GB).

[image: the old HDD in gparted]

So then I went out and got a new 1TB SSD, thinking that it would be no problem to just move the data to the new storage device.
Then the problems began:

My initial idea was using `dd` to just move the disk bit-by-bit and later move and resize the partitions.
Moving the data using `dd` worked great and I could even boot from the SSD.
Unfortunately resizing the partitions didn't work so well though.
On the new disk I now had 400GB of free, unallocated space, which I wanted to merge with both of the data partitions(sdb2 and sdb5).
To do this I obviously needed to first move the recovery partition to the right, which was very easy in all of the programs I tried.
Then comes the actual problem: moving or resizing the second data partition on the disk.
I tried using gparted and the kde partition manager to do this on linux and tried the default disk management utility on windows, but none of these could do the job.
When trying to move the partition there is always a maximum amount I can move or resize this partition, and its always zero, even though the unallocated space is directly adjacent to the partition.
I highly suspect that my problem has to do with the extended partition wrapped around this partition.

So now I basically have a few questions:

1. Why can I not move or resize this partition? (I would love to know the details, if there are any interesting ones)
2. How can I work around this restriction?
3. Is there a smarter/better/easier way to achieve my goal?
4. Why is there an extended partition in the first place? I have read, that it is automatically created and needed when having more that 4 NTFS partitions, but there are exactly 4 without it?

[image: trying to move the partition in gparted]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the HDD state where you can't increase the size?

Comment: I will do that once it finished copying again, this will unfortunately take about one more hour :(.

Comment: Why are you using Linux utilities on a Windows disk?

Comment: I cannot use the windows installation that I want to move, since this would require me to connect 2 drives to the laptop, which only has one SATA slot. I could buy a usb to SATA cable, but why would I? Additionally the old system is painfully slow (as mentioned in the question). So I have to hook up the disk to my main PC anyways and can then use windows or linux to modify the drive. As also mentioned, I tried the windows utility with no difference in behaviour. The Linux disk utilities are way easier to use, more feature complete and have better documentation for most things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on the copy...
NOT on the original disk, as it may make the copy unbootable...
It the copy becomes unbootable, you can always make a new copy from the original.

Do this with GParted. Windows own tools are useless for anything complicated.

Delete the Samsung recovery partition (sdb4) at the very end. (Nobody in his right mind will ever use that again.)
Commit that change and then check if the computer can still boot from the disk.
It it boots go back to GParted. Extend the Extented partition (sdb3) to the end of the disk. Resize the sdb5 to the new size and move it to the back. Then move the start point of the extended partition to just in front of the start of sdb5. This will make to room to extend sdb2 into the now empty space between sdb2 and sdb3.

Please note: The bootloader on sdb1 may have been setup to actually boot a special bootloader on sdb4, that will in turn (if the user doesn't select Samsung recovery mode) will boot sdb2. (Because of that sdb4 is setup as a primary partition in stead of and extended one. This fairly normal for such configurations.)
If that is the case the copy may not boot after sdb4 is removed. In this situation you just move sdb4 to the very end and resize sdb3 to fill the space in front of sdb4.
(In case of removing sdb4 it may also be possible to boot from a Windows installation media (for same Windows version as installed) and do a "repair bootfiles" in order to make it boot again without sdb4. It depends on your skill-level fixing a borked Windows bootloader.)

Comment: I will try this as soon as the disk is copied again. Thanks for the quick and long answer.

Comment: @Max7cd I have ran into similar issues a couple of times while upgrading older computers. Vendors can make a real non-standard mess of harddisk layout, especially with pre-install and recovery partitions. On my own computers I only use the pre-install to verify if the hardware works. Then I wipe the entire harddisk and do a clean installation myself. So I know how it is setup and it won't cause future issues. (And it gets rid of all the pre-installed bloatware too obviously.)